# How to use HTML Parser to fetch comments?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html-parsing, blogs

I am trying to use `HTML` parser in `ASP.NET` with `C#` to parser/fetch comments from article on news website Times of India. Here is a sample url: `http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/tech-news/software-services/Infosys-CEO-SD-Shibulals-letter-to-employees/articleshow/16832881.cms`

I tried to fetch its HTML and then use `WebGet`, `DocumentNode.SelectNodes()`, etc. to fetch the comments. But its not showing any comments in HTML of Page.

(Usually all data to be fetched is founded embedded in some `<div>` tags etc. but here no such tag is available which gives comments.)

How do I fetch the comments from this page?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ It makes it really easy to parse specific information out of html.

Comment: do you have an url which has actual comments, the url in your post does not have comments? possibly, the comments are updated dynamically on the site. that's why if you fetch html code, it does not have the comments.

Comment: You cannot get the comments using HtmlAgilityPack because they are loaded using JavaScript (you have to run the JS first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the comments by navigating to the comments URL in the case of the URL you posted it is..

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/tech-news/software-services/Infosys-CEO-SD-Shibulals-letter-to-employees/opinions/16832881.cms

Then search for

```
<div style="" class="cmt">
```

that seems to be the tag that designates the comments.

Comment: You are stating the obvious here.

Comment: Thanks...That was what im looking for. Just missed this.

Comment: @Nacereddine --  Sometimes the obvious is all people need